# Proper escaping quotes from bash to batch

Tags: bash, batch-file, escaping, cygwin

I'm trying to start from a cygwin-bash context a batch process.
But my quotes are removed or escaped with backslashes.

Sample:

```
npp="\"$(cygpath -w "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe")\""
echo "$npp"
echo cmd /c "echo start \"\" $npp"
cmd /c "echo start \"\" $npp"
```

Output:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
cmd /c echo start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
start \"\" \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe\"
```

The first and second line is the expected output.

But in the third line there are **unwanted backslashes**.
I suppose that the bash shell added these slashes always, but later they are removed by the bash shell again, but in the case of a batch-cmd context there is no process to remove the backslashes.

My question is, how to avoid the backslashes or how to remove them in the batch context?

Comment: might be because you are trying to pass everything as a single argument. maybe try `cmd /c echo start "" "$(cygpath ...)"`

Comment: @ccarton Unbelievable, it works! But it's not completly correct, as for `cmd.exe /c` there is a difference if the expression is in quotes or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a bash instance at hand, but tested on busybox (I know, not the same, just a test)

```
W:/ $ word='"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE"'
W:/ $ eval "cmd /c echo start \"\" $word"
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE"

W:/ $ word="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE"
W:/ $ eval "cmd /c echo start \"\" \"$word\""
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE"
```

Comment: It works with `eval`, but not when `cmd` is used. `cmd /c echo start \"\" $word` results in to `start "\"\"" "\"C:\Program" Files...`. I suppose that's because cmd.exe doesn't use the `bash` argument handling

Comment: @jeb, have you tried to remove the `echo`? This will leave the `cmd /c start ...` and, at least in my case it correctly executes the `start` command. At the end the `eval` is launching `cmd`.

Comment: Sorry, I now understand your use of `eval`. And it works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

To start NPP in notepad mode with foo.txt opened.

Use the cygpath `--dos` option, and the cygstart `--verbose` option:

`cygstart --verbose --wait $(cygpath --dos "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe") -multiInst -nosession foo.txt`

or let cygstart do the cygpath for us:

`cygstart --verbose --wait "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -nosession foo.txt`

or just use `cmd` if it is in your path, otherwise:

`/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/cmd.exe /c start '""' /I /WAIT 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession -noPlugin -notabbar foo.txt`

Comment: Thanks that's nearly fit for me, in my case I only have to remove the `--wait` option.  Your `cmd.exe` solution works here, but isn't quite correct, it expands to `start "\"\""` and I tried to surround the complete expression wit double quotes.

Comment: `start` has an odd command line syntax. It looks for the window title argument as an optional argument explicitly surrounded by double quotes. This, combined with the funny way `cmd.exe` handles quotes, requires this   odd quoting.  It makes more sense when you provide a window title, which is not actually used unless `cmd` starts a console window, you must enter that argument as `"title"`, which appears as `"\"title\""` when quoted by `cmd`. The equivalent using bash quoting is `'"title"'`.

Comment: For portability, you can replace the hard coded path to cmd, `/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/cmd.exe` with `$(cygpath -u "${COMSPEC}")`. This should work for all windows versions and install options. Also note the use of the /I option to `start` which restores the original cmd path, i.e., the path before cygwin added its directories to the path. I use the `CYGWIN_NOWINPATH=1` option to isolate my cygwin environment from the windows environment. This requires me to use the absolute path name for all non-cygwin executables.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, but it seems to be a bit ugly.

```
npp="$(cygpath -w "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe")"
cmd /c "set q=\"\" & (call set q=%q:~1,1%) &  call echo start %q%%q% %q%$npp%q%"
```

The second line simply creates in the variable `q` a single quote sign.
First `q` is set to `\"\"` and the `(call set q=%q:~1,1%)` sets `q` with the second character of the previous content of `q`.

And the `call ...%q%` uses these quotes.

But as said before, this seems not to be a desirable solution.